Fixing the Custom Screener below in Pine Script
It is not working. There is only one point for which the script has to choose the stocks passing through.
This will be like an Indicator, and will come below in TradingView chart. Whenever, any stock meeting the extreme volume criteria, in 30 minutes time frame, in any candle, there will be a pop-up to show stocks list for entry.
//@version=5
indicator('Extreme Volume Alert-1Apr24', overlay=true)

// Input
MAlength = input.int(title="EMA Length", defval=200, tooltip="EMA lookback period")
Trigger = input.float(title="Extreme Volume Trigger", defval=5, step=0.1, tooltip="Current volume has    to be X times above EMA to be considered Extreme")

// Volume 
Vol = volume
MA = ta.sma(Vol, MAlength)

screen() =>
    ExtVol = Vol / MA
    ExtVol >= Trigger ? true : false

// Counts
var BarCount = 0 
var ExtVolcount = 0
if close > 0
    BarCount := BarCount + 1

//------------------------------------------------------
tf = timeframe.period

s1 = input.symbol('NSE:NIFTY 50 Index', 'Symbol 1', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s2 = input.symbol('NSE:NIFTY Bank Index', 'Symbol 2', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s3 = input.symbol('NSE:Abcapital', 'Symbol 3', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')  
s4 = input.symbol('NSE:Adanient', 'Symbol 4', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s5 = input.symbol('NSE:Adaniports', 'Symbol 5', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s6 = input.symbol('NSE:BEL', 'Symbol 6', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s7 = input.symbol('NSE:BHEL', 'Symbol 7', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s8 = input.symbol('NSE:BPCL', 'Symbol 8', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s9 = input.symbol('NSE:Coalindia', 'Symbol 9', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s10 = input.symbol('NSE:GAIL', 'Symbol 10', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')    

[c1] = request.security(s1, tf, screen())
[c2] = request.security(s2, tf, screen())
[c3] = request.security(s3, tf, screen())
[c4] = request.security(s4, tf, screen())
[c5] = request.security(s5, tf, screen())
[c6] = request.security(s6, tf, screen())
[c7] = request.security(s7, tf, screen())
[c8] = request.security(s8, tf, screen())
[c9] = request.security(s9, tf, screen())
[c10] = request.security(s10, tf, screen())

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

entry_label = '***Entry***\n'
entry_label := c1 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s1) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c2 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s2) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c3 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s3) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c4 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s4) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c5 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s5) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c6 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s6) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c7 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s7) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c8 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s8) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c9 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s9) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c10 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s10) + '\n' : entry_label

lab_entry = label.new(bar_index + 10, close, entry_label, color=color.new(color.lime, 70),     textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.price, textalign=text.align_left)

label.delete(lab_entry[1])

//###############################################


Please explain what the error is.

You need to remove the brackets [] from your variable declarations. You aren't returning tuples.
Also double check your default entries for symbols. There was a symbol doesn't exist error. Once I changed all of the input symbols it worked.
c1 = request.security(s1, tf, screen())
c2 = request.security(s2, tf, screen())
c3 = request.security(s3, tf, screen())
c4 = request.security(s4, tf, screen())
c5 = request.security(s5, tf, screen())
c6 = request.security(s6, tf, screen())
c7 = request.security(s7, tf, screen())
c8 = request.security(s8, tf, screen())
c9 = request.security(s9, tf, screen())
c10 = request.security(s10, tf, screen())


Thank you so much for help, appreciate it.
